# Why does the new Belgian passport design feature comic characters?

Tags: identity-document, belgium

The new Belgian passport is featuring comic characters as its design theme.

https://www.republicworld.com/world-news/europe/belgium-unveils-new-passport-design-featuring-comic-characters-like-tintin-and-smurfs-articleshow.html

As far as I know, no other country uses motifs from popular culture as passport design teme. Perhaps the point is that Belgium is a divided society, so they were looking for a neutral motifs?

Comment: The article seems to explain this fairly clearly: "[Deputy Prime Minister and Minister of Foreign Affairs] Sophie Wilmes highlighted that ... the new passport **offers the opportunity to highlight the 9th art form, the comic strip which she underlined as the central element of [Belgian] culture**."

Comment: I read that but I am not satisfied with the explanation. As far as I know, no other country uses motives from popular culture as passport design teme. Perhaps the point is that Belgium is a divided society, so they were looking for a neutral motive

Comment: If that's the official line, then I'm afraid anything else is speculation, and we don't deal in speculation here. It's entirely possible that there's some other secret agenda behind this, but it's impossible for anyone to know that.

Comment: "no other country ... neutral motive" That really should be part of the question body, not a comment. Please edit it in.

Comment: @zagortenej What sort of answer were you expecting, then? Big Cartoon forced the government to include comic strips in their passports?

Comment: Also, I think you mean "motifs," not "motives"

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Any comment on this topic from someone who understands the identity of people from Belgium would be interesting to me

Comment: Some public statements would be good as answer, not just a single person saying something. That would only be anecdotal and not much worth.

Comment: I would have thought the Deputy Prime Minister and Minister of Foreign Affairs Sophie Wilmes would have a good perspective on Belgium.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Never underestimate the power of Big Cartoon!

Comment: Maybe what you're missing is that they are not cartoon characters (although they appeared in cartoons) but characters of [Belgian *Bandes Dessinées*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_comics) which are considered an extremely important part of Belgian culture. I find their insertion no more surprising than the picture of some famous painting would be.

Answer (score 6):

National governments routinely ornament their official documents and official items with motifs that exemplify their national culture, and have done so since at least the Copper Age, in independent developments all over the world (the Indus River Valley Civilization, Egypt, the Hittite Empire, the Sumerians, the Aztec and Inca cultures, etc.).

For example, an [Euro denominated coin](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/euro/coins/1euro/html/index.en.html), while it can be used in any Euro-zone country as currency, is distinguished by culturally distinctive images from the country that mints the coin.

Belgium decided in this case that certain comics (more properly, characters of [Belgian Bandes Dessinées](https://Belgian%20Bandes%20Dessin%C3%A9es)) exemplified its national culture and looked cute in an otherwise dreary official government bureaucratic document. As the linked article explains:

> [Deputy Prime Minister and Minister of Foreign Affairs] Sophie Wilmes
> highlighted that ... the new passport offers the opportunity to
> highlight the 9th art form, the comic strip which she underlined as
> the central element of [Belgian] culture.

No deeper explanation is necessary and there is no reason to think that the "Big Cartoon" lobby forced the government's hand in this matter.

(Note that this answer is informed by the comments to the question from multiple contributors.)

Comment: Comment about Big Carton was joke

Comment: "while it can be used in any EU country": The euro is foreign currency in some EU countries.  In those countries it can only be "used" as readily as (for example) the US dollar -- at a currency exchange window or with a merchant that accepts foreign currency (typically at an exchange rate that is unfavorable to the purchaser).  "Otherwise dreary": some other countries have made similar moves against dreariness (Switzerland, Norway, Japan, and Canada came up in some searches), although more through the use of color and UV features than by choice of subject matter.

Comment: @zagortenej I don't doubt that your comment was a joke, but the question itself seems to imply some sort of motive along those lines.

Comment: @phoog Technically you are correct and Euro-zone would have been more accurate, but that doesn't detract in any way from the point being made.